# unknown cases of the inverse galois problem

Tags: galois-theory

The problem : Given a subgroup $G$ of $S(n)$, is there a polynomial having galois
               group $G$ ?

I found some useful theorems, and I believe to remember that upto degree $11$,
 all transitive groups occur. Can anyone confirm this ?

Which is the smallest group $G$, for which it is NOT known if there is 
 a polynomial having Galois group $G$?

Comment: @f.nasim Please notice that the uncapital $galois$ is not mis-spelled: it might come from the direct application from other languages, or it could be regarded as an adjective, in which case there is no need of capitalising. Regards.

Comment: @awllower I don't know the other language case, but for adjective shouldn't it be something like `galois-group`. Thanks.

Comment: @f.nasim I think "-" means another construction of a noun: it adjoins one adjective and a noun together to form a noun; here of course an adjective can stand along for its own right. In any case, it is only a reminder, or rather a comment, as it is not the place to discuss such nuances here, I suppose. So, just look at the problem. :D

Comment: Essentially the same was [asked](http://mathoverflow.net/q/70155/6085) on MO. Besides the answer, the links in comments may also prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to a database, the only hole up to degree 19 is

17T7  L(17):2=

So, perhaps, someone finds a polynomial with degree 17 and this
galois-group.

Very astonishing, that for all other groups, at least one polynomial 
was found, if the entries in the database are valid.